# Acces function from constructor in Lua

Tags: android, class, lua, coronasdk

I have a class in Lua. In this constructor I declare the variables (in an empty table) and after I want to acces to a function of the object to insert objects in this table. My code is this:

```
local BoxClass = require("Box")
local SurpriseBox = {}
local SurpriseBox_mt = { __index = SurpriseBox }    -- metatable

function SurpriseBox.new()  -- constructor
  local object = {
    boxes = {}
  }
  SurpriseBox:CreateBoxes()
  print('constructor -> ' .. #object.boxes)  --> 0
  return setmetatable( object, SurpriseBox_mt )
end

-------------------------------------------------

function SurpriseBox:CreateBoxes()
  local box1 = BoxClass.new('palo', 'images/chestClose.gif', 'OPEN')
  local box2 = BoxClass.new('moneda', 'images/chestClose.gif', 'OPEN')

  self.boxes = { box1, box2}
end
```

After access to the function CreateBoxes() there is nothing inside the table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See my answer for the explanation. As to your code, you're duplicating table creation. That is, in your constructor you create an empty `boxes` table and in the `CreateBoxes` function you replace that table with another one. So either do not create it in the constructor or just fill it in `CreateBoxes`. Otherwise it's inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but only one question. If I create `boxes` table in constructor and I want to insert elements inside in `CreateBoxes()` function, can I do this?  `table.insert(self.boxes, element)`

Comment: Yes, you can. Since you're only inserting 2 elements there's not much difference, but in general, if you're filling an array, it's better to keep track of the number of elements in a variable (for example `index`) and then do plain assignment - `self.boxes[index] = element`. It's more efficient, as `table.insert` always checks number of items in the array and only then insert the item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `SurpriseBox:CreateBoxes()`, the `self` parameter still points to the `SurpriseBox` table, not the `object` table you created. You should probably do it like this:

```
function SurpriseBox.new()  -- constructor
  local object = setmetatable( {boxes = {}}, SurpriseBox_mt )
  object:CreateBoxes()
  print('constructor -> ' .. #object.boxes)
end
```

The key is to assign metatable before the call to `CreateBoxes()` and call it on the `object`, not `SurpriseBox`.

Comment: Works perfectly, that was my idea! Thanks for your explanation too!